# Reset meta tags using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using these two functions to set and reset meta tags after I instigate an JS application

```
function setMeta(){
        alert("meta set");
        $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, user-scalable=0');
    }

function resetMeta(){
        alert("meta reset");
        $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', ' width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.6, user-scalable=yes, user-scalable=1');
}
```

My question:
What is default value of the initial-scale propertie. If I don't reset it it stays 1.0 as it was set.

Update question: If the page where I open my JS app is scaled.The page doesn't  get set to 1.0 scale as in setMeta function when I open the dialog. Where could the problem be? The other properties like `user-scalable` work fine...

Comment: Hi sir I have one doubt.. Actually once u change user-scalable=0 then in the resetMeta() method we can't able get back as user-scalable=1. I have requirement to disable and enable zoom buttons through meta tag. Is it possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value is `1.0`, see [this page](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Web/#!nokia-browsers/symbian-browsers/browser-73/viewport-meta-tag-support.html):

> The viewport initial-scale parameter specifies the scale (zooming) of a web page the first time it is displayed. **The default value of 1.0 specifies no scaling**. Larger values up to 10 zoom in (enlarge) the page, and smaller values down to 0.1 zoom out (shrink) the page.

---

To set it to the value it was before, just store it.

```
function setMeta(){
        alert("meta set");
        oldcontent=$('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content') //store the current value
        $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, user-scalable=0');
}

function resetMeta(){
        alert("meta reset");
        $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', oldcontent);
}
```

Comment: Ohh man, thank you. I was looking for the initial-scale instead I could save all the content.

Comment: @Jacob: You're welcome :) If you want, using `split()`, you can specifically extract the initial scale.

Comment: Just another thing how can I store the value a global level.

Comment: @Jacob: It is being stored at a global level. Or, use `window.oldcontent` instead of `oldcontent`. You can even make it persist over pages, use `localStorage.oldcontent` or `sessionStorage.oldcontent`

Comment: I debug the oldContent value using all 3 techinques above and I get an empy string....

Comment: @Jacob: No, you have to replace _all_ instances of `oldcontent` in the script with the other techniques to get it.

Comment: I understand. After more debugging I found that the value is printed fine. Nothing wrong with variables. It's just not set.
This dosn't set it right: oldcontent=$('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content')

Comment: @Jacob: it will only get set if you call setMeta first. And you have to make sure that `setMeta` is setting `widnow.oldcontent` (or the other ones), and not `oldcontent`

Comment: Affocrse I completly understand and I checked twice the order of function beeing called. The value is set to "". That is the problem. It doesn't retrieve the content value right. Hope you understand me.

`window.oldcontent = $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content');`
`console.debug(window.oldcontent);`

It prints nothing

Comment: @Jacob: Are you sure that there is a meta tag of type `viewport`? (case sensitive). This works for me; could you provide a fiddle of the relevant code?

Comment: Ohhhh my bad, here is the problem `<meta name="viewport" content="">`

Comment: @Jacob: hm, I have no clue how to answer that. I think you probably should ask it in a separate question :/